# Getting single Tweet with TwitterKit/Fabric authentication failure

Tags: ios, swift, twitter, twitter-fabric

I'm trying to retrieve a single tweet and show it in my application via the `TWTRTweetView` provided in the TwitterKit. I've followed [this Fabric guide](https://docs.fabric.io/ios/twitter/show-tweets.html#display-a-single-tweet) and ended up with following code.

```
import UIKit
import TwitterKit


class SingleTweetViewController: UIViewController{


@IBOutlet weak var plainView: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()

    Twitter.sharedInstance().logInGuestWithCompletion { session, error in
        if let validSession = session {
            Twitter.sharedInstance().APIClient.loadTweetWithID("4831830029115392") { tweet, error in
                if let t = tweet {
                    let tweetView = TWTRTweetView(tweet: tweet)
                    tweetView.showActionButtons = true
                    self.plainView.addSubview(tweetView)
                } else {
                    println("Failed to load Tweet: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
                }
            }

        } else {
            println("Unable to login as guest: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            println(error?.localizedFailureReason)
        }
    }
}
```

The code generates these two errors due to authentication failure.

```
Unable to login as guest: Request failed: forbidden (403)
Optional("Twitter API error : Unable to verify your credentials (code 99)")
```

It is worth mentioning that the app successfully signs in to Twitter via the login button added following [this guide](https://docs.fabric.io/ios/twitter/authentication.html#log-in-with-twitter). Does anyone have a clue how this error could be fixed? Am I missing some code here or is the issue related to Fabric?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using Fabric applications built in option "View tweet in application" found in the same menu as the "Add login button button" option. The Fabric application then inserts proper authentication keys into the `Info.plist` file. The code provided by Fabric application seems to do the same thing as the code given on [Fabric docs](https://docs.fabric.io/ios/twitter/show-tweets.html#display-a-single-tweet) but the result differs depending on which one you use. The two code samples look like this:

Code from Fabric docs:

```
Twitter.sharedInstance().logInGuestWithCompletion { session, error in
  if let validSession = session {
    Twitter.sharedInstance().APIClient.loadTweetWithID("20") { tweet, error in
      if let t = tweet {
        self.tweetView.configureWithTweet(t)
      } else {
        println("Failed to load Tweet: \(error.localizedDescription)")
      }
    }
  } else {
     println("Unable to login as guest: \(error.localizedDescription)")
  }
}
```

Code from Fabric application:

```
Twitter.sharedInstance().logInGuestWithCompletion { (session, error) in
        Twitter.sharedInstance().APIClient.loadTweetWithID("20") { (tweet, error) in
            self.view.addSubview(TWTRTweetView(tweet: tweet))
        }
    }
```

Running the first code will give an authentication error while the second one will load a tweet without issues. The if-statement `if let validSession = session` returns a `false` and an authentication error occurs. I couldn't find what the `validSession` is exactly but it probably compares two different sets of keys or something similar.

Comment: Does this still give you an error? You should no longer have to call `loginGuestWithCompletion` anymore as the underlying network stack will do that automatically.

Answer (score 2):

You have to initialize Fabric before trying to use it which is what you're doing in your example code.

For the initialization, follow instructions from [the Fabric documentation site](https://docs.fabric.io/ios/twitter/twitterkit-setup.html). In essence, you have add the following lines to your app delegate (in addition to importing TwitterKit):

```
Twitter.sharedInstance().startWithConsumerKey("your_key", consumerSecret: "your_secret")
Fabric.with([Twitter.sharedInstance()])
```

Then copy and paste you're consumer key and secret from [fabric.io](http://fabric.io). Fabric should automatically generate these for you.

Comment: I've tried adding your code to my app delegate with my key and secret from Fabric.io but still get the same errors. Any idea? @Markus

Comment: I remember getting similar error in the past. Try cleaning the Xcode project (including Derived Data) and delete the app from the simulator/device. It could be caching problem so that should help with that.

Comment: The issue was indeed caused by invalid keys. I solved it by re-running "include tweet in application" provided by Fabric. The keys where then correctly added to Info.plist