# Twitter Kit error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, twitterkit

So I'm using the TwitterKIT from Twitter not fabric and I'm getting an error. Here is the code. I've also followed the installation of TwitterKIT exactly documented on Twitter

> [TwitterKit] Couldn't load Tweets from TWTRTimelineViewController:
>   Error Domain=TwitterAPIErrorDomain Code=99 "Request failed: forbidden
>   (403)" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Twitter API error : Unable
>   to verify your credentials (code 99), TWTRNetworkingStatusCode=403,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: forbidden (403)}

```
class TimeView: TWTRTimelineViewController{

@IBOutlet var Menu: UIBarButtonItem!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
    Menu.target = self.revealViewController()
    Menu.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
    let client = TWTRAPIClient.withCurrentUser()
    self.dataSource = TWTRUserTimelineDataSource(screenName: "PortCreditSS", apiClient:client)
    self.showTweetActions = true
    }
}
```

Comment: see this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/32498593/3901620

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never mind I fixed it. Regenerating the keys and pasting those fixed the issue

Comment: same.. very strange

Comment: same here, strange indeed